# The type Email must implement the inherited abstract method Comparable.compareTo(Object)

Tags: java, comparator

It gives these errors
The type Email must implement the inherited abstract method Comparable.compareTo(Object)
The type Email.DateComparator must implement the inherited abstract method Comparator.compare(Object, Object)
The type Email.SubjectComparator must implement the inherited abstract method Comparator.compare(Object, Object)

although I have

```
public class Email implements Comparable, Serializable
{
...

    public static class DateComparator implements Comparator
    {
        public int compare(Email email1, Email email2)
        {
            return email1.getTimestamp().compareTo(email2.getTimestamp());
        }
    }

    public static class SubjectComparator implements Comparator
    {
        public int compare(Email email1, Email email2)
        {
            return email1.getSubject().compareTo(email2.getSubject());
        }
    }

}
```

How to fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement the *Comparator.compare(Object, Object)* method. Cast the arguments to Email.  You implemented *Comparator.compare(Email, Email)*

Answer (score 1):

You had `Email` implement the `Comparable` interface.  Either *don't* implement it -- a perfectly reasonable thing to do, if you're providing a variety of comparators -- or implement the `compareTo` method directly in the `Email` class, with some sensible "natural ordering."

Answer (score 0):

Change your class signature to:

```
public class Email implements Comparable<Email>, Serializable
```

And implement the comparable method:

```
public int compareTo(Email otherEmail)
```

This is assuming of course, that you meant to make the class comparable in the first place. Currently you have nested comparators defined in the class, for whatever reason.